# Javascript Promises: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 9

Tags: javascript, promise

I am learning asynchronous programming with javascript. I have create a function to get sections and trying add them to the front page. but I'm getting and error `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 9`

Any suggestions?

```
(function() {
    const sectionEl = document.getElementById('sections-left')
    const getSection = async (url) => {
        const response = await fetch(url)

        if (response.status === 200) {
            const data = await response.json()
            return data
        } else {
            throw new Error('Unable to get section')
        }
    }
    getSection(`https://www.somwebsite.com/private/shared/public_home_facts`).then((data) => {
        return getSection(`https://www.somwebsite.com/private/shared/public_home_about`)
    }).then((data) => {
        return getSection(`https://www.somwebsite.com/msg`)
    }).then((data) => {
        sectionEl.appendChild(data)
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(`Error: ${err}`)
    })
})()
```

Comment: Be sure you want backticks `\`` for those URLs and not single quotes. `'`

Answer (score 0):

> Unexpected token < in JSON at position 9

This message usually means that the server is returning HTML instead of JSON for a response.

You can confirm this by getting text instead of json:

```
if (response.status === 200) {
        const data = await response.text()
        console.log(data);
        return data
```

This should help you spot which call is not returning JSON.

Hope this helps.